# Furnace problems after dust accumulation

Tags: furnace

I’ve been doing some DIY projects these last couple weeks and some of them have caused there to be alot of dust, one in particular is the grinding of an old brick wall I want to expose. I wasn’t thinking about what damage the dust could cause to the furnace, although I tried to capture as much as I could there was still some that got airborne. My furnace burner now ignites for about 30 seconds, then goes out. Right after this the blower motor kicks on for another minute. It seems like there’s an issue with the furnace getting overheated which is causing the flame to go out and the blower to run to try to escape all of the heat that has built up.

Another one of my projects had to do with me crawling in the attic,I had to crawl over duct work and I accidentally popped them apart. I tried to put them back together but it was a little difficult as they were installed properly to begin with. I ended up using duct tape to try and hold them together. I wasn’t sure if the furnace would somehow recognize the restriction of exhaust and thus not work properly due to a safety switch.

Here is the make and model of my furnace. Although I can’t find really anything about the manufacturer or model number online , it might help someone who knows what they’re doing. The furnace is pretty old, I would have to estimate around 20 years old.

Make- heat controllers
Serial # - CN3D104F29789657
Model number - GHI 50D2

Comment: Re the attic accident - is it duct work that broke apart (e.g. carrying conditioned air), or is an exhaust flue (where the byproducts of burning gas go outside)?

Comment: Have you changed the furnace filter?   I believe you are in a freeze now.  I had a similar issue when I lived in Ohio. It turned out to be the gas line into my house had water in them and it was freezing, lowering the pressure. The furnace would come on but only run for about 20 seconds.  I called the gas Co.

Comment: @RMDman that’s interesting, how to you mention it to the gas company , was there something they could do about it ?

Comment: @negacao I believe it was the exhaust but I’ll have to double check

Comment: @RMDman also I did change the filter but when I did it was in very bad condition, there was so much dust that I couldn’t even see through it

Comment: I know it's Christmas eve, but try a call to the utility co.  My problems were on Christmas eve as well.  They came out and put a heating cord on my meter and outside piping. I got credits for the electric on my gas bill. The issue of water in the pipes was repaired by the gas co. in the spring.

Comment: By "duct tape" you mean the foil stuff, right?

Comment: No I just used regular duck tape

Comment: If the exhaust pipe is truly damaged, I would not be surprised at the furnace turning itself off - that is a dangerous situation where the byproducts of burning gas could end up in your living space. But I imagine you'd know if it's exhaust pipe - does it go up through the roof? Is it metal and not flexible duct? (When I say "exhaust" I do not mean "supply air", I mean where the place where a gas burning heater sends the smoke outside) (edit: nevermind, I see your followup post).

Comment: i think the flue exasht would be described as pipework, not duct work, so that's probably not a huge deal, though is worth having the furnace tune-up guy take a look at next time he's out.